# android UI are look different from one screen to another

Tags: android, user-interface, fragment

I'm working with navigation drawer activity and fragment. My UI (fragment ui)are very different from a phone to and other with different screen resolution. Please I want to now how I can solve that problem. if some one have and idea he will be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking into your codebase, it is difficult to understand but my feeling is that the Layout (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, FrameLayout etc), you use, have some static padding, margin. Those will show different behavior in different screen for their resolutions. In your emulator preview, try to use different device and see the difference. Thanks